# Mysql state "Creating sort index" slow magento2

Tags: magento2, database

How to disable "Creating sort index" state on mysql, this is cause high CPU(>400%) & slowing magento. How to prevent this?

Comment: Additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here.
RAM size of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) complete MySQLTuner report 
\Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop, top & mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -x when system is busy for an idea of IOPS by device, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: For Basic analysis, additional information request, please. Post on pastebin.com or here. A) RAM size of your MySQL Host server  Text results of: B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; after minimum 24 hours UPTIME C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;  to improve reduce your SORT time required, rather than presenting a jumble of unpredictable data sequences to your customers.

Comment: Make Every Moment Count   It has been 6 weeks and you still have not posted any data that would allow me to help you.  Have you just given up on sorting your data for your customers?  How many cpu/core exist on your server?  If you have 12 cores, 400% is 33% of your available CPU power was being used when observed.   CPU% divided by  cpu/core = %busy SO  400 / 12 = 33%

Comment: Still have high CPU when sorting?  Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This issue is related to sort collection on custom product grid for latest products, best seller, etc.. at the homepage.

So, remove **Sort by** collection. Then, the issue will be resolved.

Comment: Is SORT not important for your customers predictable display of data from day to day?  Give me an opportunity to review the information requested 8/23, please.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SELECT @@sort_buffer_size;  to determine current size

Multiply the value returned by two.

In your my.cnf [mysqld] section,

```
sort_buffer_size=calculated-result
```

stop/start your instance and you should have reduction in CPU % used.